# HLK Testing - Trim Test Failure

Tags: testing, driver, developer-tools

I am working on trying to get the HLK testing to pass. In particular I am having an issue with the Trim Test. It keeps giving me a error and a warning that I am thusfar unable to figure out how to remedy.

Warn: Please ensure the StorPort ETW Registry key is set.
File=drivers\storage\tests\trimperf\testcase.cpp, Line=1011

Error: 0x0, Error 0x00000000
No ETW tracing is available.
File=drivers\storage\tests\trimperf\trimperf.cpp Line=242

The above is the warning and error I receive. Does anyone possibly know how I can get passed this and what my issue may be?

A little more information I hope helps here:

We are using a Dell Precision 3450. The OS is Windows 10 Pro - Test signing is on. The drive being tested on is a Samsung SSD 860 EVO 2TB SSD plugged into the SATA port.

I want to also add that our Driver is a Storage Filter Driver and not a Storage Port Driver.

Any guidance would be appreciated, even if it is to point to documentation on how to solve this issue.

---

I have tried to manually add the registry key based on what little I could find as a suggestion to fix the issue.

I have also tried to start a job in the Performance Monitor with the Microsoft-Windows-Storport - this also has failed to solve he issue.

I have a thought that I may not need this test but in that case would need an Eratta ID - if that is the case then help in being pointed in the right direction would be appreciated as well, so far I have not found much on this.

If more information is needed on my end I will provide it to the best of my ability.

Thank you for taking the time to read!

Comment: I know this is an SSD test. IT does not run with an old Harddrive. Though I am still uncertain how to solve the error.